# Unable to Center Banner in Responsive Layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to get the banner to center as you it sizes down to a smaller resolution as opposed to pushing the image to the right.  Here is the page I am referring to.  [Page](http://www.acuity-sports.com/newsletter/Acuity%20Sports.html)

I'm using 100% width.

```
        <!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE HEADING IMAGE - Full 100% Width // -->
            <tr class="heading">
                <td align="center" valign="top" id="preview" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; padding:0px; border-bottom:1px solid #eeeeee;">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="400" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td background="https://www.acuity-sports.com/newsletter/images/banner10.jpg" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" height="400" valign="top">
                            <img editable width="600" src="" style="max-width:600; border:0px; display:block;" mc:edit="header_image" />
                                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:350px;">
                                <v:fill type="tile" src="images/main_image.jpg" color="#ffffff" />
                                <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                                <![endif]-->

                                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                </v:textbox>
                                </v:rect>
                                <![endif]-->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- END TEMPLATE HEADING IMAGE - Full 100% Width // -->
```

Comment: Tables for layout,...not a modern approach.

Comment: @Paulie_D: I thought the same at first, but this looks like a newsletter, presumably for email, which basically has to still use the old-school table-based approach since all clients are different & none handle HTML very well.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes it is not the best approach but as mc01 said it is for an email newsletter which is a royal pain to configure for multiple email clients and different mobile devices.

Comment: Fair enough but it might make it easier if you mentioned that at the start. there are some properties which we might recommend that are no supported by email clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use css properties: `background-position` for `td` with your banner

```
background-position: center;
```

for your element will make center align.

Also you can do it via `style` attribute

```
style="background-position: center;"
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  Adding a style att does work on every client but Outlook..   For some reason it will not even display the image using a style.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE HEADING IMAGE - Full 100% Width // -->
        <tr class="heading">
            <td align="center" valign="top" id="preview" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; padding:0px; border-bottom:1px solid #eeeeee;">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="400" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" height="400" valign="top">
                        <img width="100%" src="https://www.acuity-sports.com/newsletter/images/banner10.jpg" style="max-width:600; border:0px; display:block;" mc:edit="header_image" />
                            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                            <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:350px;">
                            <v:fill type="tile" src="images/main_image.jpg" color="#ffffff" />
                            <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                            <![endif]-->

                            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                            </v:textbox>
                            </v:rect>
                            <![endif]-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

try this online demo: http://jsfiddle.net/40jhoe0x/1/

thank you